# Java - Swing Display Image Not Working

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Swing and am trying to display a simple image that I have dragged into my project using the code below. Everything compiles and runs, however, the image does not show up.

Just by the way I would really prefer doing it this way opposed to getting the image from its file path.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageProcessorApp IPA = new ImageProcessorApp();
    IPA.displayImage();
}

void displayImage() throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    BufferedImage wPic = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("url-2.jpg"));
    JLabel wIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(wPic));
    frame.add(wIcon);
    System.out.println("added image");

}
```

Comment: does `this.getClass().getResource("url-2.jpg")` return a non-null object? My guess is that the file name/path is wrong. Where, to which path exactly, did you drag the image to?

Comment: Is the image file on the classpath so the getResource method can find it? To see where the classpath is: System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you must call method .setVisible(); only after added all components in the Frame.
 Secondary - you must fix your path for Image, just add image in your project beside the Main class.
 This is worked solution :

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.io.IOException;

  /**
     * Created by Алексей on 24.11.2016.
   */
 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    displayImage();
}

public static void displayImage() throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/url-2.jpg"));

    frame.add(imgLabel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
frame.validate();
```

after adding the image, in other case, the frame will not be updated!
If that does not work, check if the resource is found!

Working version:

```
void displayImage() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        BufferedImage wPic = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("img/url-2.jpg"));
        JLabel wIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(wPic));
        frame.add(wIcon);
        frame.validate();
        System.out.println("added image");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to also put your frame related code to the very end. 
I guess this way you will avoid the need to validate it.